# Baraja plugin with opened deck on load by default

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am working on a plugin called [Baraja](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/13/baraja-a-plugin-for-spreading-items-in-a-card-like-fashion/) for spreading items in a card-like fashion.

I can't figure out from the code how to make the plugin by default to load the cards in "Rotated spread (horizontal)" fashion when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap this in document ready. For the first example in the demo it can be done like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#baraja-el').baraja();

    baraja.fan({
        speed : 500,
        easing : 'ease-out',
        range : 90,
        direction : 'right',
        origin : { x : 25, y : 100 },
        center : true
    });
});
```

You can find settings for all examples in demo page source code. Usually in majority of modern browsers you can open it with right mouse click and then selecting *"View source code"* from context menu.

Read more about document ready in [official jQuery documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: but i cant figure where to place this code. should i paste it in the html file or the jquery.bajara.js file?

Comment: Place it with your own code of course. You should not change anything in plugin code.

Comment: No change, it still opens as a single card when the page is loaded, instead i need the cards to be in "Rotated spread (horizontal)" fashion when the page is loaded.

Comment: Where is it located in demo? Just look at page source code and find according example as I mentioned.